# Update hyperlink to file with current date in name

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink

I have to send mail which contains a hyperlink every day. The link leads to a file created daily.

The path is always the same.

The file will have the current date as the name (0316, 0317, 0318).

I manually change the name of the file in the hyperlink. How can it be updated automatically? Is it possible to integrate the date function into the hyperlink?

I use this code:

```
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).openastextstream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.readall
ts.Close
End Function


Sub Data_EMail()

    Dim OLApp As Object
    Dim OLMail As Object
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim str_MsgBody As String

    SigString = "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\eForms.htm"
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)

    If Dir(SigString) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Signature Saved to C Drive to send Emails"
    End If

    Set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    OLApp.Session.Logon

    With OLMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Data " & Date

        .HTMLBody = _
         "<p>write your text here</p>" & _
         "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "file://///...../0316.xlsx" & Chr(34) & ">Data</a>" & Signature

        .Display
    End With

    Set OLMail = Nothing
    Set OLApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to just change 0316 in  "file://///...../0316.xlsx" ?

Comment: exactly. it changes every day, so i want to avoid to make it manually. it always fits the date, that's why i want to automatize it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this? Use

```
dateString = Format$(Month(Now), "00") & Format$(Day(Now), "00")
```

to hold the date string to add into your href.  I have added a debug statement to test that your string (testString) = the string with the variable added. Obviously only effective for 16/03.

No concerns about year part? And what happens across years?

Note: the optimized type function format$ and the use of "00" to pad out zeroes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim testString As String
testString = "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "file://///...../0316.xlsx" & Chr(34) & ">Data</a>"

Dim dateString As String

dateString = Format$(Month(Now), "00") & Format$(Day(Now), "00")

Debug.Print "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "file://///...../" & dateString & ".xlsx" & Chr(34) & ">Data</a>" '& Signature

Debug.Print "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "file://///...../" & dateString & ".xlsx" & Chr(34) & ">Data</a>" = testString


End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, i will check it when i am back at work and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

The date functionality in excel makes this pretty easy

You can get the current date and time using Now() or just the date using Date()

you can then pull the numerical day from the date format using
Day(Date())
and numerical month using Month(Date())

Then all there is to do is to put it in 2 digit formatting and append one to the other like so:

`myDate = Date()
DateCode = Format(Day(myDate), "00") & Format(Month(myDate), "00")
fileName = "file://///...../" & DateCode & ".xlsx"`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for!